# conexion a base de datos con phonegap

Tags: jquery, ajax, phonegap

Buen día a todos, estamos estudiando **phonegap** un poderoso **framework** multiplataforma y de fácil diseño, lo que no comprendo es la conexión a una base de datos mediante **ajax** o **jquery**. Pongo algo de lo que llevo y espero puedan de favor ayudarme con mi duda que me esta haciendo volver loco.

Tengo un formulario de login, el clásico:

Codigo
          
        
        
          Nip

y mi función con jquery para pasar los datos a mi servidor y poder comunicarlo con el archivo login.php que hace la validacion. el cual esta dentro del body para que pueda reconocerlo  el boton

```
<script>
function enviar_variables(){
    var datosCodigo = $("#codigo").val();
    var datosNip = $("#nip").val();

    $.post("https://juanssa91.000webhostapp.com/proyecto/login.php", {codigo:datosCodigo, nip:datosNip}, function(respuesta){
        alert(respuesta);
    });
}     
</script>
```

Pues pasa que cuando el ejecuto, muestra la interfaz, intento insertar los datos, presiono el botón, pero nada, no hace nada.

Answer (score 0):

Tal como has formado la pregunta, parece evidente que hay mucho código que no nos estás mostrando. Por favor, intenta mostrar más código.

En cualquier caso, si no hace nada, seguramente se deba a que no has vinculado la ejecución de la función a ningún evento HTML.

Aunque, con el código que has aportado, esto no es más que una simple suposición.